# SwiftUI onAppear not working properly when trying to read UIKit's UIDevice orientation

Tags: swiftui, device-orientation, uidevice, onappear

Using iOS14.4.2, Swfit5.3.2, XCode12.4, physical device = iPhoneXS

On appearing, I am trying to write the current device orientation into a Static property and later use it inside a View.

However, the value is not correctly written when appearing.

Here is my code (see below)

Note that `isPortrait` will always be `false` - no matter how I orient my iPhone at startup.
Especially, when the iPhone is in Portrait at startup, shouldn't the property be `true` ??

Why this strange behaviour ?

Apple should intensify device-orientation issues with SwiftUI, I think.

```
struct MyView: View {
  
    @State var isPortrait: Bool = true
 
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("text1")
            if isPortrait {
                Test("text2")      // never shown why ???
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            isPortrait = (UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait)
            print(isPortrait)  // always prints 'false' why ????
        }
    } 
}
```

And please, don't tell me to use `GeometryReader` instead since this does not work on iPad (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait
```

Comment: Thank you - this works inside `onAppear`. It is good to have a replacement - but why would the first one not work in the first place ?

Comment: I didn't find a reason for it, but it has nothing to do with your code. Most likely a bug.